# compare multiple fields in awk

Tags: awk

I have a file in which a list of attribute-value pairs are present. The file looks something like this:

```
"a b c" 1
"d e" 2
```

The code will need to look for the attribute and increment the value if it is found. I was initially working with a single word attribute and the below code worked fine. Now the requirement has changed and the attribute can be multi-word with numbers, special characters, and double-quotes.

```
#This works only if attribute is single word
% cat file1.txt 
abc 1
def 2
% var=abc
% awk -v p="$var" '$1~p {$2+=1}; {print}' file1.txt
abc 2
def 2
```

How can I get this to work now that the attribute is not just the first field but can be of any size? How can this be done with awk?

This is what I expect as output:

```
#This is file2.txt initially:

% cat file2.txt 
"a b c" 1
"d e" 2

#I should be able to execute the code passing var="a b c" on file2.txt and i am expecting the below output:

"a b c" 2
"d e" 2
```

Comment: The last field of each line is the value which needs to be incremented if the rest of that line matches

Comment: Did you try to concatenate all but the last fields and then compare that concatenated string? Also consider whether `sort < file | uniq -c` can do what you are after.

Comment: Why the "linux", "bash" and "shell" tags? Please don't do that, also read the descriptions of those tags!

Comment: Thanks Ed, you are right. i have edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

```sh
$ cat file2.txt 
"a b c" 1
"d e" 2

$ var=c

$ awk -v p="$var" '{ for (i=1; i<NF; i++) if ($i ~ p) $NF +=1; print }' file2.txt
"a b c" 2
"d e" 2
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your requirements correctly, would you please try:

```
% cat file2.txt
"a b c" 1
"d e" 2
fg 3
% var="abc"
% awk -v p="$var" '
{
    num = $NF                                           # value of the last field
    if (match($0, /"[^"]+"/)) {                         # if the attribute is enclosed with double quotes
        attr = substr($0, RSTART + 1, RLENGTH - 2)      # extract the enclosed substring as attr
        gsub(" ", "", attr)                             # pack attr by removing whitespaces
    } else {
        attr = $1                                       # if the double quotes are not present, pick the 1st field
    }
    if (match(attr, p)) num++                           # increment num if attr matches p
    print attr, num     
}' file2.txt
abc 2
de 2
fg 3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ var="a b c"
$ awk -v var="\"$var\"" 'index($0,var)==1{$NF++} 1' file2.txt
"a b c" 2
"d e" 2
```